# Replace a character in the GetFeatureInfo response

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm having a lot of floating point raster datasets in GeoServer. GeoServer automatically uses a dot (.) to separate the decimals of a value.

Is it possible to change this into a comma (,)? Either within GeoServer, or by modifying the GetFeatureInfo response so it replaces . with ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatting of a GetFeatureInfo response is controlled by a [FreeMarker template](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/freemarker.html) rather than GeoServer directly.

The [FreeMarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui.html) suggests that [number formats](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html) are determined by the locale of the machine it is running on. So it looks like you should get `,` instead of `.` if that is what your machine is set up for.

If necessary you can override the locale of the machine by setting it as an argument to the JVM that is running GeoServer using this:

```
set JAVA_ARGS=-Duser.language=fr -Duser.region=FR %JAVA_ARGS%
```

Comment: Thank you, but then all my layers change a . to a ,. Is it not possible to only change this for a certain number of layers?

Comment: Locale is an all or nothing thing, I don't think there would be any way to do this without considerable coding.